# DB response is too slow

Tags: mysql

What can be done to identify the reason for DB slowness?

When i ran the query in the morning it ran quickly & i got the output.

When i run the same query after 1 hr, it took more than 2mins.

What can be checked to identify this slowness?

All the tables are properly indexed.

Comment: "All the tables are properly indexed." Are you sure?

Comment: Maybe you have more open connections (more visitors) later. Or you have open transactions. Does it get faster again automatically or do you have to restart the server/service?

Comment: After 1 hr the query took 2 mins to respond & then later after 15 mins the same query took 0.06 secs to respond, i don't understand why & pls. help me to identify this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a single query which is running slowly, `EXPLAIN SELECT...` as mentioned by arex1337 may help you see the reason.

It would also be worth looking at the output of e.g. `vmstat` on the box whilst running the query to see what it's doing - you should be able to get a feel for whether the machine is swapping, IO-bound, CPU-bound etc.

Check also with `top` to look for any rogue processes hogging CPU time.

Finally, if the machine is using RAID, it's possible that, if a drive has failed, the RAID array could be in a degraded state, which could make disc access slower (this is only applicable in certain RAID configurations, but worth considering and ruling out).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXPLAIN <your query>` to get information about how MySQL executes your query. Maybe you get some hints about why it's slow.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;
```

Also, maybe you just have a slow query, and it was fast the second time because the result was cached?

Comment: Thanks. Query wise this will help, i want to investigate at server level as the query worked fine earlier, something wrong @ server level which am trying to investigate.